# Maven surefire plugin output test summary xml?

Tags: maven, maven-surefire-plugin, maven-failsafe-plugin

I am in a project that uses the Surefire and Failsafe maven plugins to run unit and integration tests respectively.  The output of failsafe produces a summary of the test run in `target/failsafe/failsafe-summary.xml`.  I would like to get a similar `.xml` summary report from surefire, however I can only seem to get an xml file per test suite there.

[image]

Is it possible to configure surefire to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to configure surefire to do this?

(create 1 report file/run instead of 1/test suite)

No, not without customizing surefire/surefire-report plugin.

Since the only (up-to-date) "output related" configuration options (of [surefire-plugin:test](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html)) are:

- encoding
- redirectTestOutputToFile
- reportFormat (default - "brief", alternatively - "plain" (*.txt files))
- reportNameSuffix
- reportsDirectory

And surefire-report plugin's only purpose is maven report (html!) generation.

---

For this special need, I'd recommend a custom script or (maven) plugin (basing on one of the above - they are open source). You can also try "to tackle the problem from source" by combining all of your test classes/suits into one!? :)